# How to capture combination of Insert+Tab in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, keypress, keydown

This is not a duplicate. Many similar threads discuss capturing a combination involving a modifier key.

I need to get something triggered when a shortcut key (a combination of `Insert+Tab`) is pressed from a control, say `Button`.

**Catch**:

1. This involves no modifier key like `Alt` or `Shift` for which .NET has built in checking.
2. This has `Tab` key which is not caught so easily.

**What I tried and came close:**

1) *KeyDown Event* but doesnt capture Tabs..

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte[] keystate);
static void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(((Form)sender).ActiveControl is Button))
        return;

    byte[] keys = new byte[255];

    GetKeyboardState(keys);

    if (keys[(int)Keys.Insert] == 129 && keys[(int)Keys.Tab] == 129)
    { 
        // doesn't work
    }
    if (keys[(int)Keys.Insert] == 129 && keys[(int)Keys.J] == 129)
    { 
        // works, since here this doesnt involve Tab
    }
}
```

*This works with regular combinations*, doesnt fire along with `Tab`.

2)  *KeyPreview Event* which captures `Tab` key, but I do not know how to get a combination of keys pressed

```
static void form_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
   if (!(((Form)sender).ActiveControl is Button))
        return;

   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
      //works

   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
      //doesn't hit.
}
```

**Requirement:**

1) I am not registering the event from Form class. Instead I have a utility class which creates all required events (along with other shortcuts). I just pass the instance of form to a static function. So I am quite unsure how I should utilize the various key overriding calls. Here is how I do it:

```
public frmLogin()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Utility.SetFormEvents(this);
}

static void SetFormEvents(Form f){
    //foreach control...........
}
```

But I can give up on this..

Thanks..

Comment: Could you try using [keyboard hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)?

Comment: @UweKeim I thought there could be trivial ways.. let me see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab is considered a command key, you don't actually get notified of it being pressed directly.  You could PInvoke the [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, but I think it's just easier to recognize that tab is a command key (and override `ProcessCmdKey`) and keep track of whether the Insert key is up or down.  For example:

```
static bool insertPressed;
static bool tabPressed;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if(keyData == Keys.Tab)
    {
        tabPressed = true;
        CheckForTabAndInsert();

    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

static void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
    {
        insertPressed = true;
        CheckForTabAndInsert();
        insertPressed = false;
    }
}

static void form_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert) insertPressed = false;
}
```

The drawback is that you only really get a KeyPress for tab with ProcessCmdKey, so you can only really support Insert+Tab (not Tab+Insert).  This is because Tab is used to switch context from one control to another.  Depending on your situation (i.e. in the context of a text box), you could make use of the [AcceptTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx) property to possibly just use KeyUp and KeyDown...  But, from what you posted, that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: See I am running all this in another class. How is it possible to transfer the `ProcessCmdKey` to another class?

Comment: you can call another class when you get `ProcessCmdKey`, sure.

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to move the entire overriding function to another class. See my 'requirement' section in my question